# SELECT conditional data from a table and INSERT INTO another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `A` and `B`.

Table `A` has five columns `id`, `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`.
`ID` column is unique while other columns have value 0 or 1.

Table B has 2 empty columns `id` and `s_name`.

Every time the value of an `s*` column in table `A` is 1, I want to insert that column's name (*e.g.* `s4`) and `id` against it in table `B`'s columns `s_name` and `id` respectively.

How do I do that in PHP?
I have tried to be as clear as possible. Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, post your attempts so far. What do you mean "every time"? Are you looking for SQL triggers?

Comment: I dont know the technical terms like triggers. By every time i mean id in column B can be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's always just one column that have value "1" then use this:

```
 INSERT INTO B (id, s_name) VALUES (select a.id, (CASE
        WHEN a.s1=1 THEN 's1'
        WHEN a.s2=1 THEN 's2'
        WHEN a.s3=1 THEN 's3'
        WHEN a.s4=1 THEN 's4'
        END) as s_name from A as a
        where a.s1=1 or a.s2=1 or a.s3=1 or a.s4=1)
```

else use this:

```
INSERT INTO B (id, s_name)
  SELECT id, 's1'
  FROM A
  WHERE s1 = 1
  union all
  SELECT id, 's2'
  FROM A
  WHERE s2 = 1
  union all
  SELECT id, 's3'
  FROM A
  WHERE s3 = 1
  union all
  SELECT id, 's4'
  FROM A
  WHERE s4 = 1
```

Comment: It worked! thanks Firas Rassas. Sorry i had to take my time.

Answer (score 1):

This is one form of *normalization* and is usually done by forming multiple (repetitive) queries against the denormalized table, then using `UNION ALL` to combine the parts. Indeed you can do this in a single SQL query:

```
insert into B (id, s_id)
select id, 1
from A
where s1 = 1
union all
select id, 2
from A
where s2 = 1
union all
select id, 3
from A
where s3 = 1
union all
select id, 4
from A
where s4 = 1
```

In general you would not need PHP to do this; it would be run once on a database. If you are trying to keep both the `A` and `B` representations of your data you are most likely *doing something wrong* - unless you have proven that cacheing both forms is necessary for performance. Note that storing the same data in two different places within a database will result in a maintenance nightmare; if you have to keep both, do make sure only ONE form is in any way editable, and update the other cached form from it.